# Eclipse debugging: on breakpoint jumps to code after minutes

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic12c, eclipse-wtp

I'm using Eclipse 4.19.0 with quite a large java-ear-project including about 20 subprojects.

When debugging, eclipse doesn't jump to the line of code immediately on a breakpoint. It doesn't hang. I can step through the code and the variables are shown but the current line isn't linked with the editor.

Then, after some minutes, it suddenly jumps to the right line. From now on, it jumps to the line immediately on breakpoints.

So the problem is: **it does jump to the line of code, but for the first time it takes minutes to do so.**

After restarting the server (Oracle Weblogic 12), the behaviour repeats.

In [this post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1100481/) a very similar problem is described and visualized with an animated gif. But no solution provided.

Is there anything I can do to get eclipse linking to the editor *immediately* on a breakpoint?

Comment: Abid Inamdar? ??

Comment: Which Eclipse version? What do you have in the preferences in _Java > Debug_ (there are some preferences _"may be slow"_ and _"may be even slower"_ for remote connections). In your 2 years old post you mentioned, did you followed what Ed Merks said?

Comment: @howlger Problem solved. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69113798/9826710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been a huge number of external libraries in the *Source Lookup Path*. We're using gradle. I guess when gradle configures the eclipse project it adds all referenced libs to the lookup path.

Solution is to remove everything from *Source Lookup Path* and then simply add all subprojects. Now the debugger behaves as expected.

Drawback of this solution is that the debugger cannot step into external libs until you add them one by one to the lookup path.

Comment: Do you see improvements in [2021-09 RC1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-09/rc1) (e.g. by [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=573239) and other performance improvements made in the last two releases)?

Comment: @howlger Sorry, but I currently won't use 2021-09 RC1 as it would take many many hours to set it up with the project ...

Comment: Using a separate workspace and open those projects via _File > Open Projects from File System..._ takes seconds, not hours and wouldn't affect your existing workspace.

Comment: @howlger Thanks. I'll have to wait until 2021-09 is available in the company and then I'll try it out.

Comment: That's sounds like a terrible place to work. I'm sorry for you.

Comment: @howlger No it's not terrible it's just about security guidelines.